# Text file won't open with open()

Tags: python

I need help with this exercise please. I have to ask the user if want to set an alarm, either for a specific date or for certain days of the week. In addition to printing the time adding 1 and I have to say if it is day or night (This last part of the code was made by the teacher of the course, I did all the alarm).

The code should open a .txt file but it does not, I have run the code several times and checked the Pycharm but nothing. Here it is

```
from time import sleep
import datetime

NIGHT_STARTS = 19
DAY_STARTS = 8
HOUR_DURATION = 1


def write_file_and_screen(text, file_name):
    with open(file_name, "a+") as file_text:
        file_text.write("{}{}".format(text, "\n"))
        print(text)


def week_date_to_day(day):
    days_list = {0: "Monday", 1: "Tuesday", 2: "Wednesday", 3: "Thursday", 4: "Friday", 5: "Saturday",
                 6: "Sunday"}
    day_weekday = day.weekday
    if day_weekday == days_list.keys():
        week_day_of_the_day = days_list.get(day_weekday)
        return week_day_of_the_day


def main():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    is_night = False

    want_alarm = input("Do you want to set a alarm? Yes/No ")
    if want_alarm == "Yes":

        # Aquí preguntamos si desea una alarma para una fecha específica.

        specific_date = input("Do you want an alarm in a specific date? Yes/No ")
        if specific_date == "Yes":
            date_user = input("Tell me the date. (dd/mm/yyyy) ")
            date_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_user, "%d/%m/%Y")
            if datetime.date.today() == date_format:
                write_file_and_screen("ALARM. It's {}".format(date_format), "Specific alarm.txt")
                print("ALARM. It's {}".format(date_format))

        elif specific_date == "No":
            # Aquí preguntamos si desea una alarma normal, haciendo que elija el día y la hora.

            normal_alarm = input("Do you want a normal alarm? Yes/No ")
            if normal_alarm == "Yes":
                hour_alarm = int(input("Hour of the alarm? 0/23 "))
                datetime.time(hour=hour_alarm)
                days_of_alarm_input = ""
                days_of_alarm_list = []
                print("Write End to end the loop ")
                while not days_of_alarm_input == "End":
                    days_of_alarm_input = input("Tell me the days that you want to set the alarm 0 to 6, 0 is "
                                                "Monday ""and 6 is Sunday ")
                    days_of_alarm_list.append(days_of_alarm_input)
                if days_of_alarm_input == "End":
                    for i in days_of_alarm_list:
                        if today.weekday() == days_of_alarm_list:
                            write_file_and_screen("ALARM. It's {}".format(week_date_to_day(today)), "Weekdays "
                                                                                                    "alarm.txt")
    while True:        # Se imprime la hora actual y se le va sumando una más, además de que si indica si es de día
                        # o de noche

        sleep(HOUR_DURATION)
        current_time += datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
        light_changed = False

        if (current_time.hour >= NIGHT_STARTS or current_time.hour <= DAY_STARTS) and not is_night:
            is_night = True
            light_changed = True

        elif (DAY_STARTS < current_time.hour < NIGHT_STARTS) and is_night:
            is_night = False
            light_changed = True

        if light_changed:
            if is_night:
                write_file_and_screen("It's night", "hours.txt")
            else:
                write_file_and_screen("It's day", "hours.txt")

        write_file_and_screen("The hour is {}".format(current_time), "horas.txt")
        sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run the program and I enter the necessary data for the alarm, simply the program goes to the 3rd part of the code and starts printing the time and adding 1 without opening the `.txt` file:

```
The hour is 2019-11-09 19:50:51.614472
The hour is 2019-11-09 20:50:51.614472
The hour is 2019-11-09 21:50:51.614472
The hour is 2019-11-09 22:50:51.614472
The hour is 2019-11-09 23:50:51.614472
The hour is 2019-11-10 00:50:51.614472
The hour is 2019-11-10 01:50:51.614472
The hour is 2019-11-10 02:50:51.614472
The hour is 2019-11-10 03:50:51.614472
The hour is 2019-11-10 04:50:51.614472
The hour is 2019-11-10 05:50:51.614472
```

If you need to know something else or If I did not explain myself well please tell me. (Sorry for my English)

---

Update:

The specific date alarm works! Thanks!

but there is another problem. The "normal alarm" does not. When the program is on the line `for i in days_of_alarm_list:` it skip it to `while True` 
[i = 6 , it suppose to pass the for i in days_of_alarm_list:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwJXy.png)
[But the program passes to while True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xNKD.png)

Comment: You should use a full, absolute path for file_name to ensure that it is written to the expected place.

Comment: Emm sorry but i didn´t understand, I´m a begginer  jajaja

Comment: Your code appears to try to open many differently named text files. Which one isn't working?

Comment: Weekdays alarm.txt and/or Specific alarm.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a type mismatch earlier, that's why you were going to the third part every time.

`datetime.datetime.strptime('10/11/2019',"%d/%m/%Y")` returns
`'datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 10, 0, 0)'`
`datetime.date.today()` returns `'datetime.date(2019, 11, 10)'`

replace your `if` condition with the following line:

```
if datetime.date.today() == date_format.date() :
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!, but a I have another problem, i updated the question about that.

Comment: `today.weekday()` returns an integer and your list has numbers saved as strings, and compare with each element rather than entire list. 
`if today.weekday() == int(i):`
Happy to help:)

Answer (score 0):

Your code working fine, I tested it on my machine,

In your code you'r sleeping your condition for 1 hour every time, that's why your code taking more time for execute file creation, modification.
Exactly waiting for 1 Hour every time when while condition looping

sleep method is

```
sleep(HOUR_DURATION)
```

You can check it by changing the time duration from `sleep(HOUR_DURATION)` to `sleep(5)`

Your condition will sleep just for five milliseconds

Happy codding